# Is django orm & templates thread safe?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using django orm and templates to create a background service that is ran as management command.

Do you know if django is thread safe?

I'd like to use threads to speed up processing.
The processing is blocked by I/O not CPU so I don't care about performance hit caused by GIL.

Comment: Your intentions are unclear.  Are you trying to use threading to run code in the background, or are you trying to write a background process that uses multiple threads?

Comment: @mikerobi I'm thinking about background process that uses multiple threads. I do not have web frontend at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you need run jobs in background, you should use [celery](http://celeryproject.org/)